# How to set background color of WP7 Application Icon

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created a 62x62 and a 173x173 PNG files for my WP7 app. I set the Background Image to the 173x173 PNG and the Icon to the 62x62 PNG.

The 173x173 PNG has the blue background which I like, but the 62x62 PNG has a black background.

How can I get the 62x62 PNG to have the blue background? Both PNG are transparent.

Comment: I use the free Paint.net to edit PNG files.

Comment: Where is the blue background coming from? Do you mean your theme color?

Comment: I believe Joel has the right answer. I haven't tried it yet but what he says makes sense. The programs list screen doesn't allow for a theme. So I'll have to put my own background color on the 62x62 image.

Comment: Are developing for SDK 7.0 or 7.1? Icons in my app list change color with theme, including for apps I developed with a transparent background. I believe prior to Mango this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the theme colour, note that it only really has impact on the icons pinned to the homescreen. Icons in the program's list don't have the theme colour as a background. So you can't have their colour change automatically. You will have to decide on the colour yourself and make it part of the image.

Comment: Gotcha, so instead of making the icon PNG transparent, I'll give it the background color I want. Thanks.